# Fit width of absolute element to content

Tags: javascript, css, sass, vuejs2, element-ui

I am trying to customize the tooltip's width of element-ui framework because text inside tooltip is broken incorrectly.

Here is generated tooltip element with is placed on the bottom of body tag

```
<div role="tooltip" id="el-tooltip-8061" aria-hidden="true" class="el-tooltip__popper is-dark popper-width" style="transform-origin: center top;z-index: 2031;/* display: none; */">
   <div data-v-65209316="" class="row">
      <div data-v-65209316="" class="col-5">Employee</div>
      <div data-v-65209316="" class="col-7">John Smith</div>
   </div>
   <div x-arrow="" class="popper__arrow" style="left: 77px;"></div>
</div>
```

and here is my vue code:

```
<el-tooltip placement="bottom" theme="dark" popper-class="popper-width" :popper-options="customPopperOptions">
    <template slot="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-5">
                Employee
            </div>
            <div class="col-7">
                John Smith
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
</el-tooltip>
```

and

```
customPopperOptions() {
  return {container: document.body, boundariesElement: document.body}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using bootstrap classes, have you thought about splitting them out because your 12 grid has less space to occupy on your employee tooltip. 1st off,
try evening them out:

```
       <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                Employee
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                John Smith
            </div>
        </div
```

See if that works, should split the difference. If this causes issues then you will probably need to adjust your CSS code because it looks as though your class .popper-width has a set width.

Comment: it works only for this use case, but if there is longer employee name is also incorrect broken .. yes my class popper-width is there but I didn't add any style, I am able with it add fixed width but I would like to have dynamic width to fit content

Comment: Is the popper-width class auto generated by the javascript? If this is the case you may have to override the class with !important in your CSS. It would be helpful if I could see the popper-width CSS as it is probably here now that you will need to fix the issue

Comment: its my class because i tried add my custom width like you said, but it didn't work